# Node not attached to plane when physicsbody is activated

Tags: ios, swift, arkit, physics-engine, plane

I try to let a car drive over my table via ARKit.
To detect the plane and add a 3D Object on it via ARKit couldn't be simpler and its very accurate, so everything is fine.

But when I configure the table plane as `SCNPhysicsBody.static/kinematic` and the car as `SCNPhysicsBody.dynamic` the car always flys about 10cm above the plane for no reason.
I could already find out that it depends on the mass of the car. If I set it to 0 or doesn't give the car a `SCNPhysicsBody` at all, everything work fine again.

I already activated `sceneView.debugOptions = [.showPhysicsShapes]` to see the boundingbox thats maybe to big or something, but everything looks fine.

Update:
I played a bit with the scn file and found this option to set a physics shape. After changing it to `Shape: Box` I saw a boundingbox that should not be that deep:

[image: The BoundingBox lets the car floating]

So the green box stand on the table, but it looks like the boundingbox is shifted down a bit, should be up to the spoiler.
How can I adjust them, when I open it in an 3D Editor ist stand flat on the surface.